# How difficult is it to replace a car radio on a Ford Focus 2012?

Tags: ford, audio, focus

I currently run a 2012 Ford Focus Zetec which has a radio system built into the console as shown in the picture below.

The version I have does not have built in navigation, and I would like to replace it if possible with a system that supports Android Auto.

I was wondering how easy it would be to replace the radio. Are there hidden DIN slots behind the fascia - if so is there a replacement fascia to support that? I'm also guessing that the steering wheel controls would perhaps not be compatible.

[image: Ford Focus Console]

Answer (score 1):

You can buy complete replacement kits, including the Android device; e.g see https://radio-upgrade.com/index.php?l=product_detail&p=86

You could also just buy the trim - e.g [http://www.amazon.com/Metra-99-5827B-Double-Installation-2012-Up/dp/B008MQEMJE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008MQEMJE) (note the comments on the button color, however)

The vehicle display at the top is retained, and the CD is replaced by a DoubleDIN unit (or your Android device)